# Is useRef hook a good use case for changing the style of individual item than useState?

Tags: reactjs, use-state, use-ref

I have card that rotates on click. It works for one card however if there are multiple cards, it rotates them all on single click. while i want to rotate them individually.

I am new to useRef hook and wondering if it okay to use useRef hook to achieve this or should i break it into a separate component with its own state and pass it back to main component ?

I am more concern about the right way of achieving this.

```js
function App() {

     const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
     const handleClick = () => {
          setClicked(!clicked);
     };

   return (
      <div className={`card ${clicked ? "rotate-180" : ""}`}
        onClick={handleClick}
      ></div>
   );
}
```

Comment: changes to a ref does not trigger re-renders, it's similar to a property on a class, you should a create a card component that has it's own internal state and handles it's own events, you can alway pass in a callback prop if the parent needs to respond to clicks on a specific card

Answer (score 1):

Try to move the button in a separate component with its own state for each button.

Anyway, the main difference between **useRef** and **useState** is that when the ref from useRef **is changed**, the component **does not** re-render, however, once the state from useState is changed, so does the component (**it is re-rendered**).

Comment: As far as I understand, you try to achive a state change, so I would go with a separate Btn component with useState which is trigered on every button click and changes the styles dynamically

Answer (score 1):

I recommend storing all cards information in an array and mapping them, after that assigning a key to each card, and using that key to apply conditional styling.

here is an example :

```
  const [clicked, setClicked] = React.useState({state : false,buttonID:Number});
  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setClicked({state:!clicked.state,buttonID:id});
  };

  const buttons = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];


      {buttons.map((x, i) => (
        <div
          key={i}
          className={`card ${(clicked.state && clicked.buttonID===i) ? "rotate-180" : ""}`}
          onClick={()=>handleClick(i)}
        >
          {x}
        </div>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-haibt-67wtrd?file=/src/App.js)